# How to parse document.getElementsByClassName to only include a child with an alt="value"

Tags: javascript, html

How can I change the JavaScript to change the style to "none" of all the `<div class="class1">` that have an `<img>` with the `alt="long"` and not the other ones.

I don't want to use JQuery.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="class1">
    <img alt="long" >
</div>


<div class="class1">
    <img alt="short" >
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
ar = document.getElementsByClassName('class1');
for (i = 0; i < ar.length; ++i)
  ar[i].style.display = "none";
```

This Changes both div above... How can I modify the `getElementsByClassName()` to only include the ones with `<img alt="long">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead with a query that locates all the `<img>` tags with the `alt` [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) values you're after that are [descendants](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) of `class="class1"` elements.

Then, navigate up to the `<div>` parent and set its style

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div.class1 img[alt=long]").forEach((img) => {
  img.closest("div.class1").style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
div { padding: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: max-content; }

.class1 { border-color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <img alt="long" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/long/200/100">
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <img alt="short" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/short/200/100">
</div>

<div class="not-class-1">
  <img alt="long" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/long/200/100">
</div>
```

Comment: Should be noted that this will only find the "closest" such ancestor. For instance in a case like `<div class="class1 outer"><div class="class1 inner"><img alt=long></div></div>` the `.outer` one would not be targeted. Not sure what OP would want in such a case, but worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

In [supporting browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-has) (as of today, all modern browsers but Firefox), you could use the [`:has()` relational pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has).

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div.class1:has(img[alt=long])").forEach((elem) => {
  elem.style.display = "none";
});
```

```css
div { padding: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: max-content; }

.class1 { border-color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <img alt="long" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/long/200/100">
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <img alt="short" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/short/200/100">
</div>

<div class="not-class-1">
  <img alt="long" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/long/200/100">
</div>
```

Or without JS:

```css
div { padding: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: max-content; }

.class1 { border-color: blue; }

div.class1:has(img[alt=long]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">
  <img alt="long" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/long/200/100">
</div>

<div class="class1">
  <img alt="short" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/short/200/100">
</div>

<div class="not-class-1">
  <img alt="long" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/long/200/100">
</div>
```

Note that this will differ from a `querySelectorAll(inner)`+ `closest(outer)` in that it will not stop at the closest ancestor.

Ps: if you want to do some feature detection before falling back to a more expensive solution, you can do so:

```js
const supportsCSSHas = (() => {
  // assumes a non empty document, HTML docs never are
  try { return document.documentElement.matches(":has(*)"); }
  catch(err) { return false; }
})();
console.log( { supportsCSSHas } );
```

Comment: CSS only solution is the best solution though no Firefox support would be a deal breaker